tox cannot find module
I am trying to run tox on a module.
Consider the following python package:
foo
├── tox.ini
├── setup.cfg
│   tests
│   └── test_bar.py
└── src
    ├── data
    │   └── data.csv
    ├── __init__.py
    └── bar.py

Where bar.py has:
import importlib.resources

def get_data_file(file_name):
    return importlib.resources.files("data").joinpath(file_name).read_text()

and test_bar.py has:
import bar
def test_bar():
    data = bar.get_data_file('data.csv')
    assert True

I can use this package as follows:
import bar
data = bar.get_data_file('data.csv')

Moreover, pytest passes.
However, tox returns the following error message in tests/test_bar.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bar'
Initial approach
Initially, the package had the following structure:
foo
├── tox.ini
├── setup.cfg
│   tests
│   └── test_bar.py
└── src
    └── foo
        ├── data
        │   └── data.csv
        ├── __init__.py
        └── bar.py

    

This structure is in accordance to PyScaffold, and works with tox. However, since this package only has one module, I was hoping to avoid having to import foo.bar, and instead import bar.
I tried the suggestion from https://github.com/pyscaffold/pyscaffold/discussions/399 i.e. add from .foo import bar or from . import bar in __init__.py.
However, if I then try to import bar, I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bar'.
Moreover, my understanding is that anything in the src folder is considered to be part of the package. Therefore I figured I should be able to put bar.py directly in src.
In conclusion, I believe to have the following questions:

Is it best practice to try to aim for import bar instead of import foo.bar, given that I only have 1 module
If so, is it best practice to put bar.py directly in the src folder
If so, should I configure tox differently?

